# Angular 2 Typescript parse json to object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am newbie to Angular2 and Typescript. I am learning nowadays. I try to get data from a REST service then I want to make a list and insert this data which comes from the service.
So my API link is http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1

here is my HttpTestService.ts code;

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HTTPTestService{
  constructor(private _http:Http){}
    getUser(){
      return this._http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1")
      .map(res=>res.json());
    };
}}
```

Here is my HttpTestComponent.ts;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HTTPTestService} from './http-test.service';
import { User } from './user';

@Component({
  selector:'http-test',
  template:`
    <button (click)="onGet()">Get Data</button><br/>
    <div>Output:{{getData}}</div><br/>
    <button (click) = "onPost()">Post Data</button><br/>
    <div>Output:{{postData}}</div><br/>
    <button (click) = "onPromiseGet()">Get Data(w Promise)</button><br/>
    <div>Output:{{getPromiseData}}</div><br/>
  `,
  providers:[HTTPTestService]
})

export class HTTPTestComponent{
  getData:string;
  getPromiseData:string;
  postData:string;


  constructor(private _httpService:HTTPTestService){}

  onGet(){
    console.log('Getting user now.');
    this._httpService.getUser().subscribe(        
      data =>this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
      error=>alert(error),
      ()=>console.log('Finished Get')      
    );         
  }}
```

And here is my User.ts

```
 export class User{
  constructor(public id: number,public name:string) { }
 }
```

How do I fill my `User` class and then how do I add a generic list to my `User` class.

Best regards

Comment: Do you want to create a new object with `id` and `name` only or use whole structure received from server?

Comment: server send many paramaters but i just only fill id and name to my structure. is it possible or i should write all parameter which server send ?

Comment: No, you don't have to, and tell me more about generic list in User class, what do you mean by this?

Comment: like csharp; 
var myUserlist = new List<User>();
myUserList.add(new User{id = 1,name = "aaa"})

this new User fill from by rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, just create a new `Object` of `User` type and pass desired data, in your case it is `id and name`.

```
private userList: Array<User> = new Array<User>();

onGet(){
    console.log('Getting user now.');
    this._httpService.getUser().subscribe(        
      data => this.parseUser(data),
      error=>alert(error),
      ()=>console.log('Finished Get')      
    );         
  }

parseUser(data) {
   let user = new User(data.id, data.name);
   this.userList.push(user);
}
```

To create list of users just make an array of `User` like that
`private Users: Array<User> = new Array<User>();` remember to import `User`.

EDIT.
For test purpose change this

```
@Component({
  selector:'http-test',
  template:`
    <button (click)="onGet()">Get Data</button><br/>
    <div>Output:{{getData}}</div><br/>
    <button (click) = "onPost()">Post Data</button><br/>
    <div>Output:{{postData}}</div><br/>
    <button (click) = "onPromiseGet()">Get Data(w Promise)</button><br/>
    <div>Output:{{getPromiseData}}</div><br/>

    <div *ngFor="let user of userList">
       <p>Id: {{user.id}}</p>
       <p>Name: {{user.name}}>/p>
       <br />
    </div>
  `,
  providers:[HTTPTestService]
})
```

When response come `angular` will print data :)

Comment: data => parseUser(data), should be data => this.parseUser(data) ?

Comment: thanks for your answer but when turn list it comes nothing;

   console.log('Start List') 
    for (var v in this.userList) 
    {  
      console.log("My First Element: "+ this.userList[v].id);
    }  
    console.log('End List') 

userList.Length = 0. I think it didnt parse or it didnt push correctly. Because i get data before parsing. where am i wrong ?

Comment: That's strange, maybe you have a typo, check you console for errors and I would like suggest you to use `for .. of .. loop` for example it would be `for(let user of this.userList) { console.log("user id: " + user.id) }`

Comment: Userlist.length = 0; so it didnt write anything ? are you sure that this parse method working fine ? Because you dont use any Json.parse etc ?

Comment: Referring to your service `getUser(){
      return this._http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1")
      .map(res=>res.json());
    }; ` is parsing it to JSON :). remember that evaluating callback for subscribe is `asynchronous` so check the place where you are calling this or show me the code :).

Comment: parseUser(data) {
    let stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log('stringData :' + stringData);
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(stringData);
    console.log('parsedData :' + parsedData);
    let user = new User(parsedData.id, parsedData.name);
    this.userList.push(user);
    console.log('List Count :' + this.userList.length);
    for(let user of this.userList)
    { 
      console.log("user id: " + user.id) 
   }
 }

I write like that, its working now :)I think firstly JSON.stringify,then  JSON.parse then set User class. Thank you very much :)

Comment: That's great. Honestly I don't know why you have to stringify it and parse. since `res.json()` should parse data to json and return it to callback.

Comment: I dont know exactly. If i didnt stringify and parse it doesnt bring anything. Should i ask last thing more :)? How can i show this result to html ?

Comment: Look at my EDIT to answer :). There is `*ngFor` which do exactly what `for .. of ..` it will generate `HTML` structure (including html tag where is `*ngFor`) for every element that is being iterated and then you can access it through `user` variable for example `{{user.id}}`

Comment: its great... Thank you so much :) have a nice day

Comment: Glad to help, you too :).